# How to downgrade to Titanium SDK 1.5.1 from 1.6

Tags: titanium

I wanted to develop using Titanium 1.5.1. Now when I download Titanium I am having SDK 1.2. and when update to 1.6 which is the only option I get to update, I don't get 1.5.1 SDK.

How can I get SDK 1.5.1.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps on the Appcelerator Continuous Builds site for obtaining and installing legacy builds.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Continuous+Builds

Answer (score 3):

open your titanium developer application and go to "edit" - here you can change the titanium sdk chosen for your project. no need to download the old one.

Comment: I have only 1.2 and 1.6 as the SDK version there. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help > Install new SDK and choose the version from the drop down by checking the lower combo button.Hope this will help you!.